# Duplicate bases for class

Tags: python, class, kivy

I am working on a school project, using python and kivy. I am not very familier with classes and inheritance. I created a class in the python file that contains "pass". The class is inheriting kivy's property (ListItemButton) then I use this property in kivy file to create a "ListView" and an adapter in it. My kivy App is working fine but visiual studio code shows me the error"Duplicate bases for class 'Boom'pylint(duplicate-bases)", I don't why.

I have tried changing the class name from "ToDoListButton" to "Boom". Just trying but it didn't work.

```
"""this is python file"""
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton

class Boom(ListItemButton):
    pass
```

```
"""this is kivy file"""
#: import main thelist
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton

<TodoList> """this is another class for a window in the app"""
        ListView:
            id: thelist
            adapter:    ListAdapter(data=["study"], cls=main.Boom)
```

The app is working as it supposed to but this error "Duplicate bases for class 'Boom'pylint(duplicate-bases)" is still showen in visual studio code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `ListItemButton` is already defined. You can ignore that error as long your Kivy App is working fine. It could be a glitch from pylint. You will not get this if you use PyCharm.

Try removing `class Boom`, import statement, `#: import main thelist` and replace `cls=main.Boom` with `cls=ListItemButton`.

Since you are starting your project, you might want to use [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) instead because [`ListView`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.listview.html) has been deprecated since version 1.10.0 and totally removed in version 1.11.0.